# fastify.route выполняет функцию дважды

Tags: node.js, fastify

Не могу понять почему функция выполняется 2 раза. Выложил всю функцию в которой происходит данная ошибка. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```js
async function routes(fastify, options) {

    try {

        let dir = './controller'
        var getFiles = function (dir) {
            let apiFiles = fs.readdirSync(dir);
            for (let file in apiFiles) {
                let name = dir + '/' + apiFiles[file];
                if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
                    getFiles(name, commandFiles);
                } else {
                    commandFiles.push(name);
                    const command = require(`${name}`);

                    let url = name
                        .replace('./controller/', "/")
                        .replace('.js', "")
                        .replace('index', "")
                        .replace(/\[/g, ":")
                        .replace(/\]/g, "")

                    fastify.route({
                        method: command.method,
                        url: url,
                        preHandler: async (request, reply, done) => {
                            await oauth.check(command, request, reply);
                            done()
                        },
                        handler: async (request, reply) => {
                            await command.execute(request, reply) // выполняется последовательно 2 раза
                        }
                    })

                    console.log(` dir: ${name} | url: ${url} | method: ${command.method}`)
                }
            }
        }
        getFiles(dir);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: какая именно функция вызывается два раза? или просто посмотрите дебаггер по стеку

Comment: Я поставил комментарий напротив функции. причем выше ```command.execute()``` я ставлю вывод в логи и этот вывод происходит 2 раза

Comment: у вас есть возможность именно проинспектить  call-stack? Просто из кода вашего непонятно, кто вызывает `handler`

Comment: к сожалению не имею возможности и достаточных знаний в отладке приложений на ноде. Если есть желание объяснить что к чему будет отлично.

Comment: есть npm fastify который регистрирует роутинг моей api. регистрируется каждый роут 1 раз. но выполняется 2 раза. странно что preHandle выполняется 1 раз

Comment: На самом деле сложно без рабочего кода что-то подсказать. Вижу только, что рекурсивный вызов `getFiles` в `if` не соответствует сигнатуре самой функции. Вообще не видно, откуда вы commandFiles берете.

Comment: могу наклепать минимальный рабочий вариант с ошибкой и скинуть вам

Comment: Это будет полезно

Comment: https://github.com/Artur-Frank/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш контроллер `/admin/account/reg` падает на функции `sha1` и попадает в `catch` блок контроллера. Поскольку `catch` никак не обрабатывает запрос, команда возвращает `Promise -> undefined`. Этот случай [описан в доках](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Routes/#promise-resolution) `Fastify`.

Все, что вам надо, это вернуть какое-то значение из `Promise`.
Например:

```
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return response.badRequest('', "invalid", reply);
}
```

Также на повторный вызов влияет `preHandler`. Поскольку он асинхронный, плюс вы вызываете `done()`, тем самым не дожидаясь резолва `preHandler`. Поэтому первый раз он срабатывает именно на вызов `done()` а второй раз на `Promise.resolve`. Странно, что `api` это позволяет.

Comment: Возвращение в catch тут нет. Все ошибки и возвращаемые данные я всегда проверяю. Второе выполнение функции начинается после запуска промиса и отправки запроса в mysql. Вот пруф https://imgur.com/a/iam15jl

Comment: все правильно, попробуйте вернуть и промис в `try` блоке

Comment: какой смысл если ответ промиса присваевается переменной data и потом отправляется мне в api.  Ну все же сейчас для интереса проделаю и это

Comment: нет ошибок, просто такое ощущение что поток освобождается при запуске участка кода с отправкой запроса mysql.  https://imgur.com/a/WGoIZFg.  try catch установил везде где можно... и даже обернул сам вызов функции в handler

Comment: нда, надо еще разок будет заглянуть, почему-то не дожидается промиса и запускает еще раз

Comment: нашел где promise возвращает undefined но catch не спасает... не дожидается на connection.query(***). причем я уже испробовал 3-4 библиотеки для работы с mysql и все так же повторяется

Comment: кстати, уберете  `done` из `preHandler` и все работает. Я не большой знаток fastify, так что чем могу. В доках есть [похожий кейс](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Hooks.md#prehandler), проверьте.

Comment: Да, теперь действительно проблема решена. Как противен async await в node.js... после C# так вообще к промисам и прочему привыкнуть не могу... Большое спасибо что уделили время для решения моей проблемы!

Comment: пожалуйста. было интересно разобраться. зачем вы заморачиваетесь с fastify? или это я отстал от жизни?

Comment: fastify намного легче express и по тестам дает более быстрый отклик и количество обрабатываемых запросов в секунду. Да и к тому же знакомство с node у меня получилось именно с создания небольшой api на fastify =)

Comment: дополнил текст. это скорее, рассуждение, чем однозначно правильный ответ. так что если найдете другую природу такого поведения - дополняйте

Comment: да, обязательно, с промисами я часто замечаю такое поведение, но с fastify такое впервые.